# report an error Ambiguous reference to member 'subviews'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Changes in the table a multiple-choice button style

```
NSArray *subviews = [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] subviews];/* An array of */
        for (id subCell in subviews) {
            if ([subCell isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {

                for (UIImageView *circleImage in [subCell subviews]) {

                        circleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellButtonSelected"];

                }
            }

        }
    /* change */
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  /* table Proxy method */ 
    var subviews = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.subviews
    for subCell: AnyObject in subviews {
        if (subCell is UIControl) {
            for circleImage: UIImageView in subCell.subviews {   /* report an error Ambiguous reference to member 'subviews' */ 
    /*  How to solve？*/
                circleImage.image = UIImage(named: "CellButtonSelected")!
            }
        }
    }
```

report an error Ambiguous reference to member 'subviews'

```
/**Swift, the table of custom boxes, no system, how to change/
```

Comment: Your code is a mixture of ObjC and Swift... I don't think it can compile under either swift or objective-c compiler...

Comment: I am programming with swift, OC code no problem, into a swift is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
for circleImage: UIView in subCell.subviews! {
  if let circleImage = circleImage as? UIImageView {
        circleImage.image = UIImage(named: "CellButtonSelected")!
  }                  
}
```

Comment: New problems again

Answer (score 0):

```
 The button click event custom selection button collapsed    

  for row in 0...self.collectionBookList.count {
                let indexPath=NSIndexPath.init(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
                self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition:.Bottom)
                let  subviews = self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.subviews
                for subCell: AnyObject in subviews {
                    if (subCell is UIControl) {
                        for circleImage: UIView in subCell.subviews! {
                            if let circleImage = circleImage as? UIImageView {
                                circleImage.image = UIImage(named: "delete")!
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```